# echarts - Event to know if the chart is completely rendered

Tags: echarts

Is there any event in the framework which will fire when all the rendering is completed.

I have tried with 'finished' and 'rendered' events but these events are firing multiple times for a single chart.

```
myChart.on('rendered', function () {
                            console.log("Chart rendered event fired");
                });
myChart.on('finished', function () {
                    console.log("Chart finished event fired");
        });
```

I am looking for an event which will fire only once after all the rendering is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true, `rendered` calling when render frame is completed and `finished` not quite what is expected of him but you can try to use the event-handler `one`, it calling once and with `finished` can be solution.

```js
myChart.one('finished', () => console.log('Done'))
```

Comment: With this, for sure it is firing once but I am not really sure it is firing after all the rendering is completed. For now, it seems to be working but I need to do some more testing. Thank you.

Comment: When there are large number of records like 10000+, is there something built in the framework to show a progress indicator in the chart area instead of a blank white screen?

Comment: Sure, https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.showLoading

Comment: I managed to show the loading text with this code
var default1 = {
     text: 'loading',
     color: '#c23531',
     textColor: '#000',
     maskColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
     zlevel: 0
   }
myChart.showLoading(default1);

But it does not disappear after the chart is rendered. Looks like we need to call hideLoading. How is this done in general?

Comment: Yes, you need to call `hideLoading` (https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.hideLoading) because the chart don't know about loading, it just show picture.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your quick responses. But I could not figure out where to call hideLoading function. (I mean which function or event ). Finished event is not firing. Looks think it will fire only after the loading is hidden. Any sample example of using this showLoading and hideLoading would be really helpful.

Comment: I am going to accept it as solution for the original question I have asked but setTimeout will not solve the problem because we can never guess when the chart is going to render. May be I should try with the render event when the first frame is rendered but again not sure if the event will fire. I will check and let you know. Thanks a lot again for your quick responses.

Comment: SetTimeout just for loading demonstration. Instead timeout in you charts must be real loading process. Like this https://gist.github.com/creadone/222f60c8d65b6d7d0081f2b35d608af1

Comment: With ECharts version >= 5.4.0 ".one" is still working but there is an warning written to the console that it is deprecated. I guess the more future proof solution would be track if the "rendered"/"finished" was fired once and only then run your desired function once.